# Equivalent formulation of Szemerédi-Trotter theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, additive-combinatorics

I am reading the first chapter of Adam Sheffer's book ["Polynomial Methods and Incidence Theory"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/polynomial-methods-and-incidence-theory/268C4E4946619A0301E9DC3736DDBA7F) and in Lemma 1.15 he proves an equivalent formulation of Szemerédi-Trotter theorem. Before asking my question I'll provide some background material.

> **Theorem 1** (Szemerédi-Trotter theorem). Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a finite set of $m$ points and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a finite set of $n$
> lines, both in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then we have
> $$I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})\leq
> 4|\mathcal{P}|^{2/3}|\mathcal{L}|^{2/3}+4|\mathcal{P}|+|\mathcal{L}|,$$
> where $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})=|\{(p,\ell)\in \mathcal{P}\times \mathcal{L}:p\in \ell\}|$.

> Consider a set $\mathcal{L}$ of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and an integer
> $r\geq 2$. We say that a point $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is $r$-*rich
> with respect to* $\mathcal{L}$ if at least $r$ lines of $\mathcal{L}$
> are incident to $p$. Let $M_{\geq r}(n)$ denote the maximum number of
> $r$-rich points that a set of $n$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can have. Rich points lead us to an equivalent formulation of the Szemerédi-Trotter theorem.

> **Lemma.** Szemerédi-Trotter theorem is equivalent to the claim: for every $r\geq 2$, we have that $$M_{\geq
>  r}(n)=O\left(\frac{n^2}{r^3}+\frac{n}{r}\right). \quad \quad \quad (1)$$
>
> *Proof.* We first prove that Szemerédi-Trotter theorem implies Equation (1). If $2\leq r\leq 12$, then trivially $M_{\geq r}(n)\leq
>  \binom{n}{2}\leq n^2$. Therefore, $$M_{\geq r}(n)\leq r^3\cdot
>  \frac{n^2}{r^3}+r\cdot \frac{n}{r}\leq 12^3\cdot
>  \frac{n^2}{r^3}+12\cdot \frac{n}{r}.$$
>
> Assume that $r>12$. If $M_{\geq r}(n)=0$, then there is nothing to
> prove. So we assume that $M_{\geq r}(n)>0$ and hence $M_{\geq
>  r}(n)=|\mathcal{P}_{\geq r}(\mathcal{L})|$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is a
> set of $n$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathcal{P}_{\geq
>  r}(\mathcal{L})$ is a set of $r$-rich points with respect to
> $\mathcal{L}$. For simplicity denote $\mathcal{P}:=\mathcal{P}_{\geq
>  r}(\mathcal{L})$ and it is not difficult to see that
> $$I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})=\sum_{p\in \mathcal{P}}|\{\ell\in
>  \mathcal{L}: p\in \ell\}|\geq r|\mathcal{P}|=rM_{\geq r}(n).$$
>
> On the other hand, Szemerédi-Trotter theorem gives us the following
> upper bound:  $$I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})\leq
>  4|\mathcal{P}|^{2/3}|\mathcal{L}|^{2/3}+4|\mathcal{P}|+|\mathcal{L}|=4M_{\geq
>  r}(n)^{2/3}n^{2/3}+4M_{\geq r}(n)+n.$$
>
> Combining upper and lower bounds for $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})$, we
> have $$rM_{\geq r}(n)\leq 4M_{\geq r}(n)^{2/3}n^{2/3}+4M_{\geq
>  r}(n)+n.$$
>
> It immediately implies that  $$\left(\frac{rM_{\geq r}(n)}{3}\leq
>  4M_{\geq r}(n)^{2/3}n^{2/3}\right)\lor\left(\frac{rM_{\geq
>  r}(n)}{3}\leq 4M_{\geq r}(n)\right)\lor\left(\frac{rM_{\geq
>  r}(n)}{3}\leq n\right).$$  Obviously, the second possibility is
> impossible since $r>12$. For the first and third possibilities, we
> have: $M_{\geq r}(n)\leq 12^3\cdot \frac{n^2}{r^3}$ and $M_{\geq
>  r}(n)\leq \frac{3n}{r}$, respectively.
>
> Therefore, if $r>12$, then $M_{\geq r}(n)\leq 12^3\cdot
>  \frac{n^2}{r^3}+\frac{3n}{r}$.
>
> Thus, we have shown that for $r\geq 2$, we have  \begin{equation*}
>      M_{\geq r}(n)\leq 12^3\cdot \frac{n^2}{r^3}+12\cdot\frac{n}{r} \end{equation*}
>
> Now we prove that Equation (1) implies Szemerédi-Trotter theorem. Let
> $\mathcal{P}$ be a set of $m$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and
> $\mathcal{L}$ be a set of $n$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $n^2\leq m$,
> then we have $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})\leq n\sqrt{m}+m\leq 2m$.
>
> So we assume that $n^2>m$, then let $k:=\lceil \log_2
>  \frac{n^{2/3}}{m^{1/3}}\rceil\geq 1$. WLOG, we may assume that any
> point of $\mathcal{P}$ is incident to at least one line in
> $\mathcal{L}$ since it does not change $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})$.
> We divide the points of $\mathcal{P}$ according to their richness and
> one can write the point set $\mathcal{P}$ as follows:
> $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{P}_{-}\cup \mathcal{P}_{+}$,  where
> \begin{equation*}
>      \mathcal{P}_{-}:=\left\{p\in \mathcal{P}:p\ \text{is incident to less than}\  \sqrt{n}+1\  \text{lines of} \ \mathcal{L}\right\},
>  \end{equation*} \begin{equation*}
>      \mathcal{P}_{+}:=\left\{p\in \mathcal{P}:p\ \text{is incident to at least}\  \sqrt{n}+1\  \text{lines of} \ \mathcal{L}\right\}.
>  \end{equation*}
>
> For each $j\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor \log_2(\sqrt{n}+1)\rfloor\}$, we
> define
>
> \begin{equation*}
>      \mathcal{P}_j:=\left\{p\in \mathcal{P}:p\ \text{is incident to} \  \geq 2^j\ \ \text{and} \ <2^{j+1} \ \text{lines of} \
>  \mathcal{L}\right\}. \end{equation*}
>
> We notice that
> $\mathcal{P}_{-}\subset\bigcup\limits_{j=0}^{N}\mathcal{P}_j$, where
> $N=\lfloor \log_2(\sqrt{n}+1)\rfloor$ and hence $\mathcal{P}\subset
>  \mathcal{P}_{+}\cup \left(\cup_{j=0}^{N}\mathcal{P}_j\right)$.
>
> This implies that $$I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})\leq
>  \sum_{j=0}^{N}I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})+I(\mathcal{P}_{+},\mathcal{L}). \quad \quad \quad (2)$$
>
> By definition of $M_{\geq r}(n)$, we have  \begin{equation*}
>      |\mathcal{P}_{+}|\leq M_{\geq \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor+1}(n)=O\left(\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^3}}+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=O(\sqrt{n}).
>  \end{equation*}
>
> Hence we have: $I(\mathcal{P}_{+},\mathcal{L})\leq
>  |\mathcal{P}_{+}||\mathcal{L}|^{1/2}+|\mathcal{L}|=O(n).$
>
> Now we estimate the sum
> $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{N}I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})$.
>
> *First case.* If $k\geq N=\lfloor \log_2(\sqrt{n}+1)\rfloor$, then for each $j\in \{0,\dots,N\}$, we have: \begin{equation*}
>      I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})=\sum_{p\in \mathcal{P}_j}|\{\ell\in \mathcal{L}:p\in \ell\}|\leq 2^{j+1}|\mathcal{P}_j|\leq 2^{j+1}m.
>  \end{equation*}
>
> Therefore, \begin{equation*} 
>  \sum\limits_{j=0}^{N}I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})\leq
>  m\sum_{j=0}^{N}2^{j+1}\leq m2^{N+2}\leq m2^{k+2}\leq 8m^{2/3}n^{2/3}.
>  \end{equation*}
>
> In this case, we obtain that
> $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})=O\left(m^{2/3}n^{2/3}+n\right)$.
>
> *Second case.* If $k<N=\lfloor \log_2(\sqrt{n}+1)\rfloor$, then we can write (2) as follows:
>
> \begin{equation}
>      I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})\leq \sum_{j=0}^{k}I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})+\sum_{j=k+1}^{N}I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})+I(\mathcal{P}_{+},\mathcal{L}).
>  \end{equation}
>
> We already know that
> $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})=O(m^{2/3}n^{2/3})$
> and $I(\mathcal{P}_{+},\mathcal{L})=O(n)$, so it suffices to estimate
> $\sum\limits_{j=k+1}^{N}I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})$. By definition
> of $\mathcal{P}_j$, we have \begin{equation*}
>      I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})\leq 2^{j+1}|\mathcal{P}_j|\leq 2^{j+1}M_{\geq
>  2^j}(n)=2^{j+1}O\left(\frac{n^2}{2^{3j}}+\frac{n}{2^j}\right)=O\left(\frac{n^2}{2^{2j}}+n\right).
>  \end{equation*}
>
> Since $j\leq \lfloor \log_2(\sqrt{n}+1)\rfloor$, then
> $O\left(\frac{n^2}{2^{2j}}+n\right)=O\left(\frac{n^2}{2^{2j}}\right)$.
>
> It implies that  \begin{equation*}
>  \sum\limits_{j=k+1}^{N}I(\mathcal{P}_j,\mathcal{L})=O(m^{2/3}n^{2/3}).
>  \end{equation*}
>
> In this case, we also obtain that
> $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})=O\left(m^{2/3}n^{2/3}+n\right)$.
>
> Eventually, we have shown that  \begin{equation*}
>      I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})=O\left(m^{2/3}n^{2/3}+m+n\right). \quad \text{QED} \end{equation*}

I think I understood the proof very well but I have the following question: If we have two statement $A$ and $B$, then we say that $A$ and $B$ are *equivalent* if and only if $A\Rightarrow B$ and $B\Rightarrow A$.

In the above Lemma the statement $A$ is $\left(I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})\leq
 4|\mathcal{P}|^{2/3}|\mathcal{L}|^{2/3}+4|\mathcal{P}|+|\mathcal{L}|\right)$ and the statement $B$ is $\left(M_{\leq r}(n)=O(n^2/r^3+n/r) \ \text{for all} \ r\geq 2 \right)$.

First part of the proof shows that Szemeredi-Trotter theorem (with explicit constants - the one in Theorem 1) implies that $M_{\geq r}(n)\leq 12^3\frac{n^2}{r^3}+12\frac{n}{r}$. But the second part shows that $M_{\geq r}(n)=O(n^2/r^3+n/r)$ implies $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})=O(|\mathcal{P}|^{2/3}|\mathcal{L}|^{2/3}+|\mathcal{P}|+|\mathcal{L}|).$ But in this step if you take a look at the proof the constants are implicit and I am wondering how to get explicitly $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})\leq
 4|\mathcal{P}|^{2/3}|\mathcal{L}|^{2/3}+4|\mathcal{P}|+|\mathcal{L}|$.

I hope my question makes sense. I'd be grateful for the explanation!
Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the equivalence is only intended to be asserted "up to constants", in that one would not get back the specific numerical constants stated in this version of Theorem 1 if one only had (1) to begin with.  There are a few clever tricks, such as the tensor product trick, that can sometimes derive inequalities with explicit constants from estimates that contain unspecified constants (such as the implicit constants in O() notation), but these are the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Please include in the body of the question an explanation of what "$I$" means, as in $I(P,L)$. It is used repeatedly, but never defined.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Edited. Please see Theorem 1. $I(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L})$ is the number of incidences between the point set $\mathcal{P}$ and the set of lines $\mathcal{L}$.